# Assigning same ID to pairs of names

Tags: python, list

```
nameList = ["sam", "tom", "jack", "james" , "robbie", "Lewis"]
id = 1
```

There is a nameList and an id initialised as 1.

I want to assign the name id for first 2 names in the list and then increment the id.

My code snippet so far:

```
nameList = ["sam", "tom", "jack", "james" , "robbie", "Lewis"]
id = 1
for names in nameList:
    print names + "," + str(id)
    id = id + 1
```

The desired output is:-

```
sam,1
tom,1
jack,2
james,2
robbie,3
Lewis,3
```

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and checking if the index of the string is even. If it is, increase `id`:

```
nameList = ["sam", "tom", "jack", "james" , "robbie", "Lewis"]
id = 0
for i, names in enumerate(nameList):
    if i % 2 == 0:   # if 'i' is even
        id = id + 1   # or id += 1, both are equivalent
    print names + "," + str(id) # if all elements are strings, 'str()' is not required
```

**Note** that on each iteration `i` will take numbers in the range `[0, length-1]`

Answer (score 3):

You can simply iterate the list with `enumerate` and using `(index / 2) + 1`, you can get the actual value you want to print

```
nameList = ["sam", "tom", "jack", "james", "robbie", "Lewis"]
for idx, item in enumerate(nameList):
    print "{}, {}".format(item, (idx / 2) + 1)
```

**Output**

```
sam, 1
tom, 1
jack, 2
james, 2
robbie, 3
Lewis, 3
```

Comment: I like this answer better than the accepted. No offense to the accepted, but this is simpler. + 1

Comment: Great answer, just wanted to point out the inconsistency: `(index + 2) / 1` has the plus and division flipped.

Answer (score 0):

```
for names in nameList:
    print names + "," + str((id+1)/2)
    id = id + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nameList = ["sam", "tom", "jack", "james" , "robbie", "Lewis"]

def counter(start, duplicate_amt=1):
    while True:
        for _ in range(duplicate_amt):
            yield start
        start += 1

for name, _id in zip(nameList, counter(1, 2)):
    print("{},{}".format(name, _id))
```

I prefer this way because if you want to increment it after x instead of 2 iterations, you can change it to `counter(1, x)`

Answer (score 0):

```
id=1
c=0
for name in nameList:
    if c<=2:
        c+=1
    else:
        id+=1
        c=1
    print "{}, {}".format(name,id)
```